# Makefile: for loop and break on error

Tags: for-loop, makefile

I have a Makefile with a for loop. The problem is that when an error occurs within the loop, the execution carry on.

```
SUBDIRS += $(shell ls -d */ | grep amore)

# breaks because can't write in /, stop execution, return 2
test:
    mkdir / 
    touch /tmp/zxcv

# error because can't write in / but carry on, finally return 0
tests:
    @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
            mkdir / ; \  
            touch /tmp/zxcv ; \ 
    done;
```

How to have the loop stop when it encounters an error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Micheal gives the shell solution. You should really be using make though (and then it will work with `-j`*n*).

```
.PHONY: tests
tests: ${SUBDIRS}
    echo $@ Success

${SUBDIRS}:
    mkdir /
    touch /tmp/zxcv
```

**EDIT**

Possible solution for a `clean` target:

```
clean-subdirs := $(addprefix clean-,${SUBDIRS})

.PHONY: ${clean-subdirs}
${clean-subdirs}: clean-%:
    echo Subdir is $*
    do some stuff with $*
```

Here I use a static pattern rule (good stuff™), so that in the recipe `$*` is whatever the `%` matched in the pattern (the subdir in this case).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that too, but wasn't sure how the dependencies where and what the semantics should be ;-)

Comment: I see what you mean. I have a problem though. In my Makefile, I have several goals (clean, install, ...) each looping over the subfolders and calling the corresponding goal in the subdir. I don't see how to adapt what you propose to this use case.

Comment: @Barth There are a number of ways of playing this. I'll add one to my answer.

Comment: Hi, I have just realized that addprefix doesn't have a dash in it. Maybe you want to edit your answer.

Comment: @Barth Eh? What do you mean. Looks OK to me (apart from the fact that all symbolic targets should be marked as phony: `.PHONY: ${clean-subdirs}`

Comment: @bobbogo I mean that it should say `$(addprefix clean-,${SUBDIRS})` and not `$(add-prefix clean-,${SUBDIRS})`. See http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_8.html

Comment: @Barth Hah! good catch. TVM. (Still got my holiday glasses on seemingly.)

Answer (score 11):

Either you add a `|| exit 1` to every call that potentially fails or you do a `set -e` at the beginning of the rule:

```
tests1:
    @dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
      mkdir / \
      && touch /tmp/zxcv \
      || exit 1; \
    done

tests2:
    @set -e; \
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
      mkdir / ; \
      touch /tmp/zxcv ; \
    done
```

Comment: You can make things slightly shorter with `&&` and `||`, something like `mkdir / && touch /tmp/zxcv || exit 1`